# Comparison of Generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Why does this code prints False?

```
    class Program
{
    public static void OpTest<T>(T s, T t) where T : class
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s == t);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string s1 = "string";
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(s1);
        string s2 = sb.ToString();
        OpTest(s1, s2);
    }
}
```

Do I understand correctly that when compared, they are compared not as strings, but as objects, which is why not their values are compared, but the addresses to which they point?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: No generics are required: `Object o1 = s1; Object o2 = s2; Console.WriteLine(o1 == o2);` will print out `False`;

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I'd argue that that's a contrived example. I agree that this does have something to do with generics. OP is clearly passing two string objects to `OpTest`, so one could reasonably expect `T` to be `string`.

Comment: System.String provides an operator overload for operator==().  But operators are not generic, so you get the System.Object flavor of the operator.  Consider Equals() instead.

Comment: @DavidG: Sorry, I can't see any *boxing* here since `string` is a `class`, not `struct`. `Console.WriteLine(typeof(string).IsValueType ? "struct" : "class")`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs for the `==` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator):

> For predefined value types, the equality operator (`==`) returns `true` if the values of its operands are equal, `false` otherwise. For reference types other than `string`, `==` returns `true` if its two operands refer to the same object. For the `string` type, `==` compares the values of the strings.

Since `T` cannot be guaranteed to be a value type as it's generic, the compiler must assume it is a reference type.

Comment: I feel this needs some more explanation given "For the string type, == compares the values of the strings." - s1 and s2 are both strings but it is clearly not comparing on values of the strings...

Comment: @Chris You caught me in the middle of adding that :)

Comment: The perils of hitting save too early! ;-)

Comment: Indeed, I usually tell people off for doing that too!

Comment: In fact, `T` is specifically restricted from being a value type... `where T : class
`

Answer (score 2):

I would normally go and agree with you in the comments, but your example is especially good.

> Do I understand correctly that when compared, they are compared not as strings, but as objects, which is why not their values are compared, but the addresses to which they point?

That is actually not true.

As stated in the [`==`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator) documentation,

> For reference types other than string, `==` returns true if its two operands refer to the same object. For the `string` type, `==` compares the values of the strings.

In your particular case, the reason is you're casting them as generics before comparing them. But if those were string objects, the **value** would be compared.

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to create a non-generic `OpTest` method to confirm what's happening. The generic method treats the parameters as `Object` types and does not use the `==` overload for `String`, which is a special case to compare the values.

In both cases the parameters are type `String` but the generic method treats them "generically" when making the comparison.

```
void Main()
{
    string s1 = "string";
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(s1);
    string s2 = sb.ToString();
    TestClass.OpTest(s1, s2);
    TestClass.OpTest<string>(s1, s2);

    // OpTest: s is System.String, t is System.String
    // True
    // OpTest<T>: s is System.String, t is System.String
    // False
}

public class TestClass
{
    public static void OpTest(string s, string t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"OpTest: s is {s.GetType()}, t is {t.GetType()}");
        // Uses String's == operator, which compares the values
        Console.WriteLine(s == t);
    }

    public static void OpTest<T>(T s, T t) where T : class
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"OpTest<T>: s is {s.GetType()}, t is {t.GetType()}");
        // Uses Object's == operator, which is a reference comparison
        Console.WriteLine(s == t);
    }
}
```